# Gatsby View Page Source not showing HTML

Tags: seo, html

I'm trying to get my HTML code to show on view page source for SEO purposes. When I visit another Gatsby website, such as https://afsp.org/ for example and look at the view page source, and you try searching for some HTML on the page, it'll show up.

However, for my Gatsby site, none of the HTML that's actually rendering and showing up on my browser is present in the view page source. Is there any easy fix to a problem like this?